# Pass parameters from directive to callback

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable, angularjs, directive

I'm trying to define a directive `sortable` which wraps jqueryui's sortable plugin.

The angular code is:

```
module.directive('sortable', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var startIndex, endIndex;
        $(element).sortable({
            start:function (event, ui) {
                startIndex = ui.item.index();
            },
            stop:function (event, ui) {
                endIndex = ui.item.index();
                if(attrs.onStop) {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.onStop, startIndex, endIndex);
                }
            }
        }).disableSelection();
    };
});
```

The html code is:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ol sortable onStop="updateOrders()">
         <li ng-repeat="m in messages">{{m}}</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

The code of `MyCtrl`:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.updateOrders = function(startIndex, endIndex) {
        console.log(startIndex + ", " + endIndex);
    }
}
```

I want to get the `startIndex` and `endIndex` in my callback `updateOrders` and do something with them, but it prints:

```
undefined, undefined
```

How to pass these parameters to my callbacks? Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`scope.$apply` accepts function or string.
In this case using function would be simpler:

```
  scope.$apply(function(self) {
    self[attrs.onStop](startIndex, endIndex);
  });
```

Don't forget to change your html code to:

```
<ol sortable onStop="updateOrders">
```

(Removed the `()`)

Comment: `self[attrs.onStop]` is actually a string, not a function. `self[attrs.onStop](startIndex, endIndex);` is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that `on-stop` attribute need to be set as "updateOrders" (remove parens from your html code).  self == scope, and you defined `scope['updateOrders']` in your controller code.

Comment: Thanks @toshshimayama you comment  "scope.$apply accepts function or string." really helped me understand scope.$apply. This makes understanding the information more bearable: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 19):

This fiddle shows hot callback from a directive passing parameters. Main trick is to use the scope to pass a function.
http://jsfiddle.net/pkriens/Mmunz/7/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).
directive('callback', function() {
    return { 
        scope: { callback: '=' },
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(scope.callback('Hi from directive '));
            })
        }
    };
})

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.cb = function(msg) {alert(msg);};
}
```

Then the html looks like for example:

```
<button callback='cb'>Callback</button>
```

Comment: it works with binding `'='`, but not with `'&'`. Any ideas why?

Comment: You've forgotten function params here `<ol sortable onStop="updateOrders()">` changet it for `updateOrders(startIndex,endIndex)` and will work

Answer (score 13):

**Alternative 1**

If you don't have an isolate scope for this directive, I would use the $parse service for that:

In the controller:

```
...
$scope.getPage = function(page) {

   ...some code here...

}
```

In the view:

```
<div class="pagination" current="6" total="20" paginate-fn="getData(page)"></div>
```

In the directive:

```
if (attr.paginateFn) {
   paginateFn = $parse(attr.paginateFn);
   paginateFn(scope, {page: 5})
}
```

**Alternative 2**

Now, if you have an isolate scope, you can pass parameters to it as a named map. If your directive is defined like this:

```
scope: { paginateFn: '&' },

link: function (scope, el) {
   scope.paginateFn({page: 5});
}
```

Comment: The alternative 2 explained on this response is actually the one angular uses itself to implement parameterized callbacks on most event directives

Answer (score 0):

taking @Peter Kriens answser a step further you can just check for the name of a  on the scope and call it directly.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).
directive('anyOldDirective', function() {
    return { 
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                if (scope.wellKnownFunctionName) {
                      scope.wellKnownFunctionName('calling you back!'); 
                } else {
                      console.log("scope does not support the callback method 'wellKnownFunctionName');
                }
            })
        }
    };
})

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.wellKnownFunctionName= function(a) {console.log(a);};
}
```